# CQWP display posts from multiple blog sites - NumComments doens't display

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, blogs, cqwp

We've just upgraded SharePoint from 2007 to 2010.

I've edited a CQWP that points to a site containing multiple blog sub-sites, and it grabs the latest posts from these sites, and displays the latest 5 on my homepage.

I can get all fields to display, except the @NumComments - which is frustrating because I found it really useful.

It works fine if you point to an individual "Posts" list, but not when you point to an entire site and select the content type to Posts.

I've also tried this with an OOTB CQWP, and I get the same result.

What I've tried so far:

1. Adding the NumComments to the DataMappings property in the CQWP.
2. Adding the NumComments field to the CommonViewFields property, then displaying it in the Item.xsl.
3. Creating a lookup column of the # Comments column and try to grab that data.

That's roughly about it without using Designer (which I don't have access to).

Is this a known issue with SharePoint? It used to work perfectly in 2007, but stopped after the upgrade.

I'm about out of ideas, so any advice would be appreciated.